# How to extract timed ID3 metadata from HLS stream in ExoPlayer?

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I have an M3U8 file located here: https://vcloud.blueframetech.com/file/hls/13836.m3u8

This video contains timed metadata every single second. My goal is to read this metadata from ExoPlayer. I currently have the following in my `MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.test.exoplayermetadatatest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.metadata.Metadata;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.metadata.MetadataOutput;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.TrackGroup;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.TrackGroupArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelectionArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MetadataOutput, Player.EventListener
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context);

        PlayerView view = findViewById(R.id.player);

        view.setPlayer(player);

        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
            new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(context, "app-name"));

        HlsMediaSource hlsMediaSource =
            new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse("https://vcloud.blueframetech.com/file/hls/13836.m3u8"));

        player.addMetadataOutput(this);
        player.addListener(this);

        player.prepare(hlsMediaSource);

        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTracksChanged( TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < trackGroups.length; i++ )
        {
            TrackGroup trackGroup = trackGroups.get(i);
            for ( int j = 0; j < trackGroup.length; j++ )
            {
                Metadata trackMetadata = trackGroup.getFormat(j).metadata;
                if ( trackMetadata != null )
                {
                    Log.d("METADATA TRACK", trackMetadata.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMetadata ( Metadata metadata )
    {
        Log.d("METADATA", metadata.toString());
    }

}
```

When the app loads I see the `METADATA TRACK` log appear a single time, but the `METADATA` log never appears once. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got a bit of a long answer here...

## The Issue

So first, I noticed that ***my exact solution*** worked in ExoPlayer 2.1.1 but not in 2.10.1. This led me to think there had been a regression with ID3 metadata, so I reached out to Google about this via GitHub. They were quick to respond and noticed that there's actually an issue with the metadata in my video. The `data_alignment_indicator` bit is supposed to be 1 for every packet which is the **start** of an ID3 tag, and 0 for every packet which is a continuation of a previous ID3 tag (in case an ID3 tag is too large to fit in the 64 kilobyte limit of a single tag). For our content, this bit is ***always*** getting set to 0 - meaning that there's no "start of an ID3 tag" anywhere.

The older version of ExoPlayer did not check for this, and therefore did not properly support metadata over 64 kilobytes. The new version ***does*** check for this, but therefore can't read our busted video

---

## The Solution

The obviously ***correct*** answer is to fix our content, but we have over 100,000 videos with malformed metadata so fixing them all would take a lot of time and money. Instead, we wanted to find a player-side solution. Here's what I was able to do:

#### 1. Pass a custom `HlsExtractorFactory` to the `HlsMediaSource.Factory` instance:

```
HlsMediaSource hlsMediaSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
    .setExtractorFactory(new HlsExtractorFactoryProxy())
    .createMediaSource(Uri.parse("https://vcloud.blueframetech.com/file/hls/13836.m3u8"));
```

#### 2. Create a custom HlsExtractorFactory

I could not extend `DefaultHlsExtractorFactory` and did not want to implement my own extractor factory from scratch, so instead I went with a [Proxy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern)

```
    public class HlsExtractorFactoryProxy implements HlsExtractorFactory
    {

        private DefaultHlsExtractorFactory internal = new DefaultHlsExtractorFactory();

        @Override
        public HlsExtractorFactory.Result createExtractor (
            Extractor previousExtractor,
            Uri uri,
            Format format,
            List<Format> muxedCaptionFormats,
            DrmInitData drmInitData,
            TimestampAdjuster timestampAdjuster,
            Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaders,
            ExtractorInput extractorInput
        )
            throws InterruptedException, IOException
        {
            HlsExtractorFactory.Result result = internal.createExtractor(
                previousExtractor,
                uri,
                format,
                muxedCaptionFormats,
                drmInitData,
                timestampAdjuster,
                responseHeaders,
                extractorInput
            );

            if ( result.extractor instanceof TsExtractor )
            {
                return createNewTsExtractor(
                    0,
                    true,
                    format,
                    muxedCaptionFormats,
                    timestampAdjuster
                );
            }

            return result;
        }

        private HlsExtractorFactory.Result createNewTsExtractor (
            @DefaultTsPayloadReaderFactory.Flags int userProvidedPayloadReaderFactoryFlags,
            boolean exposeCea608WhenMissingDeclarations,
            Format format,
            List<Format> muxedCaptionFormats,
            TimestampAdjuster timestampAdjuster
        )
        {
            @DefaultTsPayloadReaderFactory.Flags
            int payloadReaderFactoryFlags =
                DefaultTsPayloadReaderFactory.FLAG_IGNORE_SPLICE_INFO_STREAM
                | userProvidedPayloadReaderFactoryFlags;
            if ( muxedCaptionFormats != null )
            {
                // The playlist declares closed caption renditions, we should ignore descriptors.
                payloadReaderFactoryFlags |= DefaultTsPayloadReaderFactory.FLAG_OVERRIDE_CAPTION_DESCRIPTORS;
            }
            else if ( exposeCea608WhenMissingDeclarations )
            {
                // The playlist does not provide any closed caption information. We preemptively declare a
                // closed caption track on channel 0.
                muxedCaptionFormats =
                    Collections.singletonList(
                        Format.createTextSampleFormat(
                            null,
                            MimeTypes.APPLICATION_CEA608,
                            0,
                            null
                        ));
            }
            else
            {
                muxedCaptionFormats = Collections.emptyList();
            }
            String codecs = format.codecs;
            if ( !TextUtils.isEmpty(codecs) )
            {
                // Sometimes AAC and H264 streams are declared in TS chunks even though they don't really
                // exist. If we know from the codec attribute that they don't exist, then we can
                // explicitly ignore them even if they're declared.
                if ( !MimeTypes.AUDIO_AAC.equals(MimeTypes.getAudioMediaMimeType(codecs)) )
                {
                    payloadReaderFactoryFlags |= DefaultTsPayloadReaderFactory.FLAG_IGNORE_AAC_STREAM;
                }
                if ( !MimeTypes.VIDEO_H264.equals(MimeTypes.getVideoMediaMimeType(codecs)) )
                {
                    payloadReaderFactoryFlags |= DefaultTsPayloadReaderFactory.FLAG_IGNORE_H264_STREAM;
                }
            }

            TsExtractor extractor = new TsExtractor(
                TsExtractor.MODE_HLS,
                timestampAdjuster,
                new TsPayloadReaderFactoryProxy(payloadReaderFactoryFlags, muxedCaptionFormats)
            );

            return new HlsExtractorFactory.Result(
                extractor,
                false,
                true
            );
        }

    }
```

This class only exposes one public method, per the `HlsExtractorFactory` interface: `createExtractor`. This method runs the `DefaultHlsExtractorFactory`'s `createExtractor` method and, if it produces a `TsExtractor`, replaces it with its own custom version of `TsExtractor` (`TsExtractorProxy`).

To create this custom `TsExtractorProxy` I copied the entire contents of the `createTsExtractor` method from [the `DefaultHlsExtractorFactory` class](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/hls/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/source/hls/DefaultHlsExtractorFactory.java) and changed a single statement:

```
new TsExtractor(
        TsExtractor.MODE_HLS,
        timestampAdjuster,
new DefaultTsPayloadReaderFactory(payloadReaderFactoryFlags, muxedCaptionFormats));
```

```
new TsExtractor(
        TsExtractor.MODE_HLS,
        timestampAdjuster,
new TsPayloadReaderFactoryProxy(payloadReaderFactoryFlags, muxedCaptionFormats));
```

#### 3. Create the `TsPayloadReaderFactory` Proxy

As above, I needed to create a proxy here. This one exposed two public methods: `createInitialPayloadReaders` and `createPayloadReader`. I only needed to adjust the implementation of `createPayloadReader`

```
    public class TsPayloadReaderFactoryProxy implements TsPayloadReader.Factory
    {

        private DefaultTsPayloadReaderFactory internal;

        public TsPayloadReaderFactoryProxy(int payloadReaderFactoryFlags, List<Format>  muxedCaptionFormats)
        {
            internal = new DefaultTsPayloadReaderFactory(payloadReaderFactoryFlags, muxedCaptionFormats);
        }

        @Override
        public SparseArray<TsPayloadReader> createInitialPayloadReaders ()
        {
            return internal.createInitialPayloadReaders();
        }

        @Override
        public TsPayloadReader createPayloadReader (
            int streamType, TsPayloadReader.EsInfo esInfo
        )
        {
            if ( streamType == TsExtractor.TS_STREAM_TYPE_ID3)
            {
                return new PesReader(new Id3ReaderProxy());
            }
            else
            {
                return internal.createPayloadReader(streamType, esInfo);
            }
        }

    }
```

As you can see more plainly here, when dealing with stream of type `TsExtractor.TS_STREAM_TYPE_ID3` instead of instantiating an `Id3Reader`, I instead instantiate an `Id3ReaderProxy`

#### 4. Create the `Id3Reader` Proxy

This class has ***five*** public methods, but only one needs to be adjusted: `packetStarted`. Instead of passing along the `flags` parameters, I overwrite it with `TsPayloadReader.FLAG_DATA_ALIGNMENT_INDICATOR`

```
    class Id3ReaderProxy implements ElementaryStreamReader
    {

        private Id3Reader internal = new Id3Reader();

        @Override
        public void seek ()
        {
            internal.seek();
        }

        @Override
        public void createTracks (
            ExtractorOutput extractorOutput, TsPayloadReader.TrackIdGenerator idGenerator
        )
        {
            internal.createTracks(extractorOutput, idGenerator);
        }

        @Override
        public void packetStarted ( long pesTimeUs, int flags )
        {
            internal.packetStarted(pesTimeUs, TsPayloadReader.FLAG_DATA_ALIGNMENT_INDICATOR);
        }

        @Override
        public void consume ( ParsableByteArray data ) throws ParserException
        {
            internal.consume(data);
        }

        @Override
        public void packetFinished ()
        {
            internal.packetFinished();
        }

    }
```

---

With all of that hard work done, I can now get metadata events despite my busted ID3 tags

Comment: Hello, @Stevendesu can you post complete example code.

Comment: @Benjamin I've got plenty of code examples in my answer -- what exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: which method to implement in ExoPlayer to get the metadata.

Comment: '@Override
    public void onMetadata ( Metadata metadata )
    {
        Log.d("METADATA", metadata.toString());
    }'   i added method but not gettting executing callback.

Comment: I have metadata tag                                                                                                                                                 #EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=5058864,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=4870800,CODECS="avc1.640029,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1920x1080,FRAME-RATE=29.970,CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
playlist1080p.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2657019,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=2560800,CODECS="avc1.640029,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1280x720,FRAME-RATE=29.970,CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
playlist720p.m3u8

Comment: onTracksChanged() on onMetadata()

Comment: @Benjamin what you just posted looks like an M3U8 (`#EXTM3U` tag, `#EXT-X-VERSION` tag, and a handful of other tags). M3U8 tags are different from ID3 metadata, which is embedded in the TS files themselves. If you want data from the M3U8, try listening for `onTimelineChanged`. Within that method you can use `Player.getCurrentManifest()` to get details about the M3U8

Comment: ok i will try it Thanks Do you Know any example of player.getCurrentMainfest().

Comment: Thanks, Brother it is really helpful if you know any example please share the link

Comment: @Benjamin I found the suggestions (to use `onTimelineChanged` and `getCurrentManifest`) upon Googling "exoplayer get m3u8 details": https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/6848